# How to get keys from nested dictionary in a pythonic way

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have some items in a nested dictionary and I need to match if any word in a sentence matches the values in the dictionary. If it does, it returns all the keys from the nested list.

What I have tried so far:

```py
animals = {
  'vertebrates': {
    'warm_blooded': {
      'mammals': ['bear', 'tiger', 'lion'],
      'birds': ['eagle', 'ostrich', 'duck']
    },
    'cold_blooded': {
      'reptiles': ['turtle', 'crocodile'],
      'amphibians': ['frog', 'toad']
    }
  }
}

line = 'lions live in the savanna.' 

for key1, value1 in animals.items():
  for key2, value2 in value1.items():
    for key3, value3 in value2.items():
      if any(word in line for word in value3):
        print ([key1, key2, key3])

>>> ['vertebrates', 'warm_blooded', 'mammals']
```

Currently it does what I need. What I want to know if there's a way to re-write this code in a more pythonic (elegant) way as this for loop might get longer if there's more levels in the dictionary to to tranverse through.

Comment: Build a reverse index of your `animals` dict so you have {'lion': ['vertebrate', 'warm_blooded', 'mammal'], ...}` - this will make the lookup much easier AND faster (you don't have to traverse the whole dict each time). You'll need recursion to properly handle dicts of arbitrary depths when building this reverse index.

Comment: You could use this: https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/

Comment: @Petronella Could be a good opportunity to demo it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple method using recursion which keeps track of keys along the way. This should illustrate how you would do this for arbitrary lengths.

```
def key_match(data, to_match, found):
    for k, v in data.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            key_match(v, to_match, found + [k])
        else:
            if any(word in line for word in v):
                print(found + [k])

found = []
key_match(animals, line, found)

['vertebrates', 'warm_blooded', 'mammals']
```

Answer (score 1):

Could make a recursive function that keeps track of the path, and prints the path when an animal is found in `line`.

```
def search_animals_rec(animals, line, path):
    for k, v in animals.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            search_animals_rec(v, line, path + [k])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for animal in v:
                if animal in line:
                    print(path + [k])

search_animals_rec(animals, line, [])
```

Or using `any()`:

```
def search_animals_rec(animals, line, path):
    for k, v in animals.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            search_animals_rec(v, line, path + [k])
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            if any(animal in line for animal in v):
                print(path + [k])
```

Output:

```
['vertebrates', 'warm_blooded', 'mammals']
```

**Note:** The above obviously doesn't handle all edge cases, but it shows how you could approach a recursive brute force solution. A more efficient solution would be build a reverse index as pointed out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I like the [flatten-dict](https://pypi.org/project/flatten-dict/) module, might come in handy in a few operations :

```
from flatten_dict import flatten
flat = flatten(animals)
print(flat)

{('vertebrates', 'warm_blooded', 'mammals'): ['bear', 'tiger', 'lion'],
 ('vertebrates', 'warm_blooded', 'birds'): ['eagle', 'ostrich', 'duck'],
 ('vertebrates', 'cold_blooded', 'reptiles'): ['turtle', 'crocodile'],
 ('vertebrates', 'cold_blooded', 'amphibians'): ['frog', 'toad']}
```

You won't find lions in any of the values, but take away the 's' and you'll find lion:

```
line = 'lion live in the savanna.'
#used a set to avoid duplication
words = set(line.strip('.').split())
print(words)
{'in', 'lion', 'live', 'savanna', 'the'}


[key for word in words for key,value in flat.items() if word in value ]

[('vertebrates', 'warm_blooded', 'mammals')]
```